# Check whether or not a user-defined literal has already been defined

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

C++11 has introduced user-defined literals. So, we can have cool things like

```
constexpr std::complex<double> operator""i(unsigned long long d) {
    return std::complex<double>{0., static_cast<double>(d)};
}

constexpr std::complex<double> operator""i(long double d) {
    return std::complex<double>{0., static_cast<double>(d)};
}
```

What happens if these operators were already defined? Is there any possibility to check this and define the operators above only if they don't exist?

Comment: If you want to stay clear of conflicts with other libraries, put the operator in your own namespace.  If you're afraid people might `#include` it twice, put an `#ifdef` `#define` guard.

Comment: Just pointing out that your literal operators are not correct.  There needs to be a space between `""` and `X` and `X` must begin with a `_`

Comment: You can check whether macros are defined, but user-defined literals are not macros. They're defined with the `operator` keyword and structured like functions, so it's best to think of them as functions. With that in mind, would you ask about ways to check whether *functions* are defined, and only define a new one if it's not already? You're essentially asking a special case of that general question.

Comment: @rr- Or maybe use a `#pragma once` guard :3

Comment: Except it's non-standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, the literal operator `i` is part of the standard. I just wanted to know, whether or not, it's possible to detect its existence.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes that standard can do that.  Us lowly user cannot.

Comment: @rr- But it's supported by all major compilers.

Comment: @NathanOliver There doesn't need to be a space since [CWG 1473](http://wg21.link/cwg1473). That's what allows `operator ""if()` to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned with a literal name clashing with a non-user defined literal (`like 0l` for `long`), then §2.13.8/1 (N4296) specifies that:

> If a token matches both user-defined-literal and another literal kind, it is treated as the latter. [Example: `123_km` is a user-defined-literal, but `12LL` is an integer-literal. —end example] The syntactic non-terminal preceding the ud-suffix in a user-defined-literal is taken to be the longest sequence of characters that could match that non-terminal.

If you are concerned with other libraries name clashes, it's usually a good idea to put literals in some namespace `literals`; at least this is what Boost and the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) does. This will prevent name clashing.

In any way, if there are more competing overloads to the user-defined literal operator, then §2.13.8/2 (N4296) specifies that:

> A user-defined-literal is treated as a call to a literal operator or literal operator template (13.5.8). To determine the form of this call for a given user-defined-literal `L` with ud-suffix `X`, the literal-operator-id whose literal suffix identifier is X is looked up in the context of L using the rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1). Let S be the set of declarations found by this lookup. S shall not be empty.

Also notice that §17.6.4.3.4/1 (N4296) specifies that:

> Literal suffix identifiers (13.5.8) that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

So your `i` suffix there is illegal.

Comment: @0xbadf00d My version of VS2015 does.  you need to have `using namespace std::literals;` as the literal are in that namespace and not in `namespace std`.